# Can we save multiple shipping and billing address of customers?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, magento2.4, billing

I want to save multiple shipping and billing addresses of customer, If customer is logged in and on checkout page, when customer will add a new address that should be auto saved in his account and next time when customer will place order, then on checkout page when customer will click on address then customer will also be able to choose shipping and billing details from saved details in his cart ?

I am using Magento 2.4.0.

There is any solution is available ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the default Magento installation, there is the possibility to save multiple addresses per customer (for both shipping and billing) during the checkout process. You just have to check the **'Save in address book'** checkbox (which by default is checked).

The customer is able to view/ edit these addresses in 'My account / Address Book' area and also is able to choose any of these saved addresses in next purchases OR add new ones as well :)

Please check the below screenshot of the new shipping address form on checkout. Something similar is available for billing in the next step.

[image]